# SQL Query Problem: How Many Students have one or more blood donations in 2016?

Tags: sql

I am a high school student and am currently working on an exercise about **SQL**, which is this query that made me stuck for an hour and still couldn't solve it. The table schema is as follows:

Table

[image]

The question my teacher gave me was: **How any Students have one or more blood donations in 2016?**
 Thanks for any generous help.
The SQL I tried to run is

```
SELECT COUNT(*)   
  FROM DONA        
 WHERE StudID IN (SELECT StudID
                    FROM DONA
                   WHERE YEAR(DonDate)= 2016
                   GROUP BY StudID
                  HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
 GROUP BY StudID
```

And I still couldn't figure out how to COUNT the number of students.

Comment: Show the attempt that you have made to answer the question.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for help with homework, but we do like to see that you have made some attempt yourself and are not just trying to get someone to do it all for you

Comment: I've added the attempt I tried to answer the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can join both the tables and use the keyword DISTINCT to find DISTINCT students-

```
SELECT COUNT(StudID)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT StudID
          FROM DONA D
         WHERE YEAR(DonDate) = 2016) T;
```

Comment: I am not sure why would we need to join tables, because I am only suppose to find out the number of students which can be counted by StudID? Also, When I put the SQL inside Mircosoft Access, it said _Syntax Error(missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(DISTINCT D.StudID)'_

Comment: @ChingToJeremyWong, Please try the edited version. Also when you are using MS Access, why you have tagged Mysql in the question.

Comment: I am so sorry. I am new here and sure it was a mistake, I will remove the tag now. The SQL code did run through and it is what I expected. Thanks! But can I have some advice on how to make sure if I was writing my code correct in exam? Also, how to develop a sense on how to perform an SQL correctly.

Comment: @ChingToJeremyWong, The only way to perform a SQL correctly is to practice it so much. Experience have no shortcuts. Just practice it daily not only for exam.